# How to provide a service to extensions joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am trying create a joomla component. In that component I need to store some phone numbers and those numbers should be provided when an extension asks for them. How can I achieve this? Please direct me if there is comprehensive tutorials.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question exists in the [**Joomla Stack Exchange**](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3579/joomla-3-x-extension-development-tutorial-for-a-beginner-developer) site here, with links, suggestions and references to a bunch of resources around Joomla Development.

Furthermore in JSE you can find great assistance for specific questions during your development attempt.

Comment: Thanks I am new to Joomla.
And the post in Joomla.org did not help much.
:(

Comment: But still I could not found an answer to my question.
:(
My component stores a list of phone numbers. It should provide a method or a service to any other extension or component such that delivering a list of contact details when asked.
How can I achieve this?
Any hint??

Answer (score 0):

The Joomla! support site has some links to component development:

http://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Component_Development

I see that you tagged 2.5, but version 3 is the new stable version. There is an example V3 component here:

http://lendr.websparkinc.com/

When I started, I looked at an existing extension which was similar to what I wanted and went from there.